# How to autoformat with efm-langserver

Tags: neovim

I just want autoformat on save, I don't want it to have any delay.
And they say `efm-langserver` is best choice.
After I installed via AUR `yay -S efm-langserver`, that's only I know what to do.

How do I connect this to my nvim instance ?
So I have autoformatting on save ?
I understand I need multiple autoformatters depending on which language I'm working, but I don't understand how to setup each of them so they work as they should, in nvim.

What's the deal here, why I can't just run a few commands and have functional autoformat on save, why everywhere I search, I see how to setup autoformat like I'm some sort of rocket scientist and need to know all configs